# Escaping designated CSS class

Tags: jinja2

I'm trying to come up with a way to use jinja to escape a certain css class. Example:

```
<div class="code"> <center> ... more example html code ... </center> </div>
```

where the

```
<center>
```

tag is visibly written in the post. Again, I want ONLY the code class to escape.  Any hints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want ONLY your class code to be escaped, then you need to pass it in as a separate variable like so:

```
{{ classcode|e }}{{ Your other unescaped code here }}
```

I hope this helps you.